# wordpress error url image when upload change "htpp" not "http"

Tags: wordpress

wordpress error url image when upload change "htpp" not "http"

See this image:

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Check `Wordpress Address` and `Site Address` in `Settings -> General` options.